# POST data from within while loop not passing to new page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am populating a dropdown list from a database using a while. I am pulling names. The page will populate the list just fine. When I go to submit the form the data that is within the while loop will not pass onto the second page.

Code from sending page:

```
<?php   
include 'connect.php';

$TickID = $_POST['ticket'];
$EID = $_POST['employee'];
$techs = mysql_query("SELECT TechID,fname FROM technician") or die(mysqli_error());

echo "<form action='assign-send.php' method='post'>";
echo "Who would you like to assign this ticket to? <select><option></option>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($techs, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    echo "<option  name=\"Tech" . $row['TechID'] . "\" value=" . $row['TechID'] . ">" . $row['fname'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select> ";

echo "<input type='hidden' name='TickID' value=" . $TickID . ">";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='EID' value=" . $EID . ">";
echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Assign Ticket'>";
echo "</form>";
?>
```

Code from recieving page:

```
<?php

$TechID = $_POST['TechID'];
$TickID = $_POST['TickID'];
$EID = $_POST['EID'];

echo $TechID . $TickID . $EID;
// mysql_query("INSERT INTO assignment (`TechID`, `TickID`, `EID`)
                            // VALUES ('$TechID', '$TickID', '$EID')") or die(mysql_error()); //store information as variable

// header(location:'manage_assign.php');
?>
```

Currently only the TickID and EID values are sent because they are retrieved from a previous page, but the TechID data from within the while loop doesn't make it.

Comment: `<select>` has `name` attribute, not `<option>` - `echo "<option  name=\"Tech"`

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. It's awful and is being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. Always be absolutely **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) using `$_POST` data.

Comment: I'm not just starting out and I know that mysql_query is deprecated. Right now I'm just using whta I know and when time allows learning the new mysqli syntax. Thank you for the warning and the help though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your `<select>` doesn't have a `name` tag.

It should be:

```
<select name="TechID">
   <option></option>
</select>
```

You can now access the value of the selected options via this:

```
$my_selected_option = $_POST['TechID']; //The option value selected
```

Answer (score 0):

html `SELECT` has the attribute `name`, `OPTION` has not.

```
<select name="Tech">
    <option value="rowId01">rowName01</option>...
</select>
```